# How to use Scanner to assign value to multiple variables based on regex

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, scanf

I am getting input from console using Scanner. Expected input format is CR127-0772. I would like to extract 3 different values from that input: first one is string 'CR', second one is 127 and third one is 0072.
This can be performed in C using scanf

```
scanf("%s%d-%d", &st, &a, &b)
```

How can I do same task using java? I don't see how I can use regex with Scanner.
Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: No. That `scanf` won't work. Try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, Java *couldn't* do it, because java doesn't use pointers. The best you could hope for is a method that returns a list/array of values.

Secondly, "no"; there's nothing similar in the JDK that does this kind of thing.

However, you can do it fairly simply in as many lines of code as you have variables:

```
String input = "CR127-0772"; // given this got from console

String st = input.replaceAll("\\d.*", ""); // delete from 1st digit onwards
String a = input.replaceAll("^\\D+|-.*", ""); // delete leading non-digits or dash onwards
String b = input.replaceAll(".*-", ""); // delete everything up to a dash
```

This uses regex to match what you *don't* want and "delete" it by replacing with a blank.

Answer (score 0):

You can just scan it to a string, then set the variables to substrings of that string (parsed for ints as necessary).

```
String s = scanner.nextLine();
String st = s.substring(0,2);
int a = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(2,5));
int b = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(6));
```

This does assume that the string is always two characters and the first int is always three digits. The second int can be arbitrarily long.

Comment: That was my first thought, but the digits are not of fixed length.

Comment: In that case, you could either parse it manually (look for the first number and then the hyphen and set the substrings accordingly) or use regex as others have suggested. Regex is the smarter way.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible using `Scanner` since this class works with a single delimiter. What you should do here is manually parse the `String` with a desired format.

Here's an example of how to do this:

```
String data = scanner.nextLine();
String stringPart = data.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", ""); //remove all non letter chars
int[] numbers = Arrays.stream( //convert to Stream the result of
    data.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z]", "") // remove all letter chars
        .split("-")                 // and split by "-"
    ).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt) //map the array of String to a stream of int (not Integer)
    .toArray(); //convert the stream into an array int[]
```